# Q: Is it possible to decrypt sensitive information(url with ftp user and pass) securely in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, security, encryption, google-chrome-extension, cryptography

I am using CryptoJS and I am wondering if this is the right approach to upload to a apache server(I am not a security expert), any suggestion is welcomed

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you seek help in decrypting stuff or uploading?

Comment: The answer to your question is of course always yes, any sufficiently strong runtime can perform encryption or decryption. If it is secure depends on the protocol, implementation and attack vectors or threat model. Generally however, you need TLS to be secure.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you for your reply, I am wondering now how to make use of  TLS to keep my secrets private

Comment: There is a part on message passing in chrome extensions. I'd use a web-technology over the aging FTP solution. If required just put a web frontend before your FTP server, if just because plain FTP is a horrible piece of technology, especially if you want to provide security within a secure environment (double connections, firewall rules etc.). Or replace the FTP server altogether.